# Localisation on a SAAS application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, saas

**Scenario**

We have a SAAS product that has an Admin back-end with a public front-end. We want to give the user the option to change what language their front-end displays. There will be the option of 7+ different languages. Our product is built on C# and MVC3. The front-end only contains about 400 words. What is the best way to handle this? Could I store the different languages in resx files and have a flag in the DB to say which language the admin has chosen?

So the admin selects his language from a dropdown list and then all his public facing side will convert to that language.

I have never done anything like this before so any advice on potential pitfalls would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource files are the most common way to solve it. And storing the language choice in a database is a good idea.

I would use `OnActionExecuting` in your base controller to set the current language (`Thread.CurrentUICulture`)

**Update**

Specify the correct culture in the beginning of each request (in your base controller)

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var cultureId = ((YourUserObj)Session["CurrentUser"]).PreferedLanguage;
    var userCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureId);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = userCulture;
}
```

Then let .NET load the correct resource files.

Comment: Thanks @jgauffin, so i'm on the right track with my assumptions.                    So if have this `protected override string GetSubject()
            {
                string subject = GetLocalizedEmailString("CompanyRegistrationSubject", this.UserCulture);

                return subject;
            }`

Comment: I would set `Thread.CurrentUICulture` to let the .NET framework automatically use the correct culture instead of specifying it on every localization method.

Comment: The thing is I don't want .NET to automatically choose it. By default it will be English no matter what domain address the person is on. I want the admin to have the choice of what language to display. So if I added a column onto my company table, something like 'Language_Setting' and had it as int 1-9. 1 being default and English and the rest being available languages. How would I get my resx to realise what language to use?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that you specify which controller to use at the beginning of the request. Read my update

Comment: typo. Should say "which language to use"

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. Sorry I was a bit confused. So I'll pull CultureId above as an int from my database and set that to the CurrentCulture?

Comment: yep. will make .NET use the correct resource files. The int should be a locale id as specified here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: 1 last question. I've just added an emails.fr-FR.resx file in my resources folder and now I have lots of issues with my .dlls not found. Did I add the resx file wrong or is there something else I must do? sorry this is my first time working with resx files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3979/discussion-between-jgauffin-and-noel)